# Sending mail from a user supplied email address

Tags: email

I have setup mandrill within my app, emails work fine.
I'm being asked to set the 'from' address to a user inputted address (their email address).

I have tested this with my gmail address and the mail sends ok.

However I don't know if:
A - Will setting the 'from' address to not my own business email address work every time (i'm hearing it might bounce as not authenticated)?
B - If it does work do we have to notify the user that emails will be sent with their email address?

**Update:**

The email is in the fashion of:
From: User email (sanitized - do not worry about the email address)
This is to confirm you entry in XXX, any queries call us XXX.. blah
[display selections from forms]

Comment: There are too many unspecified circumstances.  On the face of it, if the user supplied their own address and authorized you to send email on their behalf, everything should be fine.  However, if they mistyped it, and/or if their domain admin has set a draconian SPF policy, and/or if the recipient is paranoid about forgeries, and/or your forgery is very clumsy, it might not work as you hope.

Comment: There is no forgery from our end,  I am developing a data collection app that is hosted by us, users sign up and can collect data for their users that they add.  I just wanted to know if we can legally use their email address if they know it will be used for all respondent emails regarding confirmation emails and such.  and the technicality of that which you mention,  so if they do use strict SPF rules it may stop the emails sending?

Comment: I mean forgery in the technical sense that you are putting in a `From:` address which is not yours.

Comment: Repeat: There are too many unspecified circumstances. Show us the mail you are sending "before" and "after" and we can judge whether it looks sane.

Comment: So maybe I should add a clause that,  any SPF records they may have in place in their records could affect the emailing process.

Comment: This is something that you really should not be doing. First, it won't work much of the time. Second, it'll get you marked as spam virtually everywhere.

Comment: Thats why im asking,  as that is what i had thought.  My only question then is, how do companies like mailchimp do it where you can use your domain.  Is that all down to you adding mailchimp to your domains SPF/DKIM?